# Match content between IF code block

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to ensure some stored procedures should not have a `RETURN` statement, except for the last one. For this task I'm trying to use regular expresions on my PowerShell scripts.
My strategy is to check every `IF @@ERROR<>0` block and perform another search inside of them. How can I match content of every `IF` block of this SQL query?

```sql
    --Some code here...

        IF @@ERROR<>0
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('MY ERROR HERE. %s',1,16,@STORE_PROCEDURE_NAME)
            GOTO ROLL
        END

    --More code here...

        IF @@ERROR<>0
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('ANOTHER ERROR HERE. %s',16,1,@STORE_PROCEDURE_NAME)
            GOTO ROLL
        END 

    --more code here...

IF @@ERROR<>0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('MAIN ERROR %s',16,1,@STORE_PROCEDURE_NAME)
ROLL:
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RETURN
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Are you basically just asking how to capture something between IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ... and END?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I found a way

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Select-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) with a regular expression like this:

```
IF .*\s+BEGIN([\s\S]*?)END
```

and select just the groups from the result:

```bsh
... | Select-String 'IF .*\s+BEGIN([\s\S]*?)END' -AllMatches |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  Select-Object -Expand Groups |
  Where-Object { -not $_.Groups } |
  Select-Object -Expand Value
```

The regular expression matches the keyword `IF` followed by a space and optional other text on the same line, one or more whitespace character, the keyword `BEGIN`, and the shortest amount of text (non-greedy match) up to the next occurrence of the keyword `END`. The subexpression between `BEGIN` and `END` is grouped with parentheses so it can be extracted from the full match.

Answer (score 0):

With the following Regex `/(If @@ERROR<>0\s+BEGIN)(.*?)(end)/sig` I can get the content between the IF and END. Please note that only matches the inmediate END, so actually is matching the END of BEGIN of some blocks.

[DEMO CODE](https://regex101.com/r/lO6rW4/1)